# add callback functionality in a JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to create a javascript class which opens a jQuery dialog and allows the user to select an option then returns the selected value in a callback.

...similar to how the [jQuery Alert Dialogs](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/alerts/demo/) do it.

> jPrompt(message, [value, title, callback])

```
jPrompt('Type something:', 'Prefilled value', 'Prompt Dialog', function(r) {
    if( r ) alert('You entered ' + r);
});
```

[Here is a **DEMO**](http://users8.jabry.com/captdragon/dev/dialogChoose.html) of what i have so far. But if you notice, the value gets set imidiately, and i want it to wait until the user clicks OK. If the user clicks Cancel, then it should return null or empty string.

Here's my **Javascript Class**:

```
var namespace = {};
(namespace.myChooser = function () {
    var _dialog = null;
    /** 
    * Function : onButtonCancel
    */
    function onButtonCancel() {
        _dialog.dialog("close");
        return null;
    }
    /** 
    * Function : onButtonOK
    */
    function onButtonOK() {
        _dialog.dialog("close");
    }
    /** 
    * Function : Initialize
    */
    function Init() {
        var dialog_options = {
            modal: false,
            disabled: false,
            resizable: false,
            autoOpen: false,
            //height: 460,
            maxHeight: 300,
            zIndex: 500,
            stack: true,
            title: 'My Chooser',
            buttons: { "OK": onButtonOK, "Cancel": onButtonCancel }
        };
        _dialog = $("#myDialog");
        // create dialog.
        _dialog.dialog(dialog_options);
        _dialog.dialog("open");
    }

    return {
        Choose: function Choose() {
            Init();
            var myChoice = $("#myOptions").val();
            return myChoice;
        }
    }
}());
```

And i want to be able to do something like this:

```
namespace.myChooser.Choose(function (myChoice) {
       $("span#myChoice").text(myChoice);
    });
```

**SOLUTION:**
This is what finally did it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myButton').click(function () {
        namespace.myChooser.Choose(function (x) {
            console.log(x);
        });
    });

});

var namespace = {};
(namespace.myChooser = function (callback) {
    function _show(callback) {
            var dialog_options = {
                modal: false,
                disabled: false,
                resizable: false,
                autoOpen: false,
                //height: 460,
                maxHeight: 300,
                zIndex: 500,
                stack: true,
                title: 'My Chooser',
                buttons: { 
                    "OK": function () {
                        if (callback) callback("OK");
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        if (callback) callback("Cancel");
                    }
                }
            };
            _dialog = $("#myDialog");
            // create dialog.
            _dialog.dialog(dialog_options);
            _dialog.dialog("open");
    }

    return {
        Choose: function (callback) {
            _show(function (result){
                if (callback) callback(result);
            });
        }
    }
}());
```

Comment: That's not a class, that's an object!

Comment: Functions are objects in JS, you can just have a parameter f in your Choose method, keep a reference to it in your closure and do f() when you're ready to call back.

Comment: @Raynos Same difference. JS doesn't have real classes, only prototypes and objects.

Comment: @Thor84no not same difference, a prototype is a "class". If your not using prototypes your not using classes

Comment: If you're going to be nitpicky, prototypes are most definitely *not* classes. Classes are rigid structures that defines all objects of that type, prototypes can be cloned and altered completely at run time. Prototypes have far more in common with objects with no set structure than a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Choose: function Choose(cb) {
    Init();
    var myChoice = $("#myOptions").val();
    return cb(myChoice);
}
```

Should do what you want

Comment: sorry, not working :/. I get the same results. What i want is after the user has chosen a value, then the values shows.

Comment: So store the function reference in your object as I mentioned in a comment, then call it when you're ready..

Comment: @Thor84no: Please post and answer with an example of what you're talking about. I can't picture what you are saying.

Comment: Both of you were saying the same thing... i was just not understanding.... I've posted my solution and given it to Raynos since he answered first. Thank you anyway Thor84no, your a scholar and a gentleman.

Answer (score 1):

Add another variable where you have `var _dialog`, call it something like `var _callback`. Then in your `Choose` function, add a parameter to get the callback function and store it, something like:

```
Choose: function Choose(f) {
    _callback = f;
    ...
}
```

Then when you're ready to call the callback function (I presume this is in onButtonOK/onButtonCancel), call the callback function using `_callback(parameter);`